# How to send a tick tuple on start of topology as well?

Tags: apache-storm

Tick tuples in storm are fired every 'emitFrequency' seconds.
If i understand correctly, the first time it is fired after 'emitFrequency' seconds. Is there a way to fire tick tuple at the start of the topology as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to do a periodic task in the bolts, we use tick tuples for the same.
If we want to do that task at the start of a topology as well, then we can perform the task in the prepare method of the bolt.